# Passing data to Reactstrap modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, reactstrap

I have some categories in my application. For each category, I'd like to add some images. So I added one Modal in reactstrap to show a modal window to add some files and descriptions. So far everything is Good. But the problem comes when I click on the launch modal button (add the file here), I'm unable to pass the id to the Modal. I tried to set a value to a variable using the useState hook but it will get a value only after the modal is closed.

My initials states like

```
const [categories, setCategories] = useState([])
const [categoryId, setCategoryId] = useState()
const [modal, setModal] = useState(false)

const toggle = (id) => {
    setCategoryId(id)
    setModal(!modal);
}
```

Then my code for showing categories

```
{ categories.map( cat => (
    <div className="card border-0 rounded-0 img-thumbnail">
        <img src={'assets/images/image_upload.jpg'} value={t._id} className="img-thumbnail" onClick={()=>toggle(cat._id)} alt="..."/>
    </div>               
)) }

<Modal 
    isOpen={modal} 
    toggle={toggle} 
    centered={true}
>
    <ModalBody>
        <div className="p-2">
            <form>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input type="file" className="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1"/>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Caption Title"/>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <textarea className="form-control" placeholder="Description" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-form">Upload</button>
                <span onClick={toggle} style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} className="ml-2 btn btn-form-outline">Cancel</span>
            </form>
        </div>
    </ModalBody>
</Modal>
```

I'm getting the category id only after the modal is closed. How can I set the value along with modal window????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `toggle` is also getting invoked when the modal gets opened & closed. You could have the `toggle` function specifically just for the setting of the state if the modal should be closed or open and have the setting of the `id` in a separate call.

```
const toggle = () => {
    // setCategoryId(id) // remove this
    setModal(!modal);
}

<img onClick={()=>{toggle(); setCategoryId(cat._id)}} />
```